# Downcasting and optional: is this code idiomatic?

Tags: swift

I want to make sure I am getting the syntax right in both cases the class is a super or derived class? Any issues with the following code?

```
class A {

}

class B : A {
    var y = 42
}

// #1

func test(x: A?) -> String {
    return
        (x as? B!)?.y == 42 ? "YES" : "NO"
}

let a: A? = A()
print(test(a))

let b: B? = B()
print(test(b))
```

Example of code using this syntax (dataTaskURL):

ObjC:

```
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]] && [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] != 200) {
```

Swift ObjC-like:

```
if response.isKindOfClass(NSHTTPURLResponse.self) && (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode != 200 {
```

Better Swift?

```
if (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse!)?.statusCode == 200 {
```

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: I did :-) and it works! I am just not sure if this is the right way to do it 'nicely' and 'safely'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Swift way (it is both safe and nice):

```
if (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 {
```

It uses *conditional casting* and *optional chaining* to both test that the class is `NSHTTPURLResponse` and that the `statusCode` is `200`.  Note that you don't need `!` after `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

If `response` is another class, then `(response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)` will return `nil`, thus the entire optional chain will return `nil` and since `nil != 200` the test will fail.

Comment: Thanks. I  accepted your answer. Any idea why the compiler doesn't even warm me when I use the extra '!'?

Comment: I'm not sure it's wrong, but certainly unnecessary. The result of a conditional cast is always an optional.